# SQL Foreign key to two different tables

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, data-modeling, liquibase

I have a problem like
Table A:
-- TableBCId
Table B:
-- Id
Table C:
-- Id

I am looking for a way to create a foreign key table A where an entry can be either in table B or table C

Example entries:
Table A:
 --  TableBCId: 1
 --  TableBCId: 2
Table B:
-- Id: 1
Table C:
-- Id: 2

I want to avoid if possible:
- Two columns in table A
- Default values
- Additional tables
- Creation of an base entity is not possible

Every idea welcome

Comment: I thought of creating a view which joins both tables and use this as base -> but this would make links between my tables visible.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question using [proper terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) ? A foreign key is defined **in the table**, not **to table**. The table containing the foreign key is called **child table**. The foreign key refers to the primary or unique key in the another table. This table is called **parent table**. I really don't know which table in your question is the child table and which one is the parent table, and which one containt primary or unique keys.

Comment: This is a faq. Just googling your title will give a trillion hits. People shouldn't be answering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a insert/update trigger on your Table_A.

Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table_a_trgr
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    on Table_a
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
      c_row NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      SELECT count(*) 
      INTO c_row
      FROM (
              SELECT ID FROM table_b WHERE id = :NEW.TableBCId
            UNION ALL
                SELECT ID FROM table_c WHERE İd = :NEW.TableBCId
          )
      ;
      IF c_row < 2 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error, Foreign Key');
      END IF;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: Beware though that a trigger is not a **constraint**.  It won't stop someone deleting a record from TABLE_B that is "referenced" in TABLE_A.  It doesn't even 100% guarantee that the corresponding record in TABLE_B or TABLE_C exists at the point that the TABLE_A insert/update is committed.

Answer (score 3):

The **normal** way to implement this requirement is with 2 columns, 2 foreign key constraints, and a check constraint to ensure exactly of of the columns populated (if this is a requirement):

```
create table a
  ( ...
  , b_id references b
  , c_id references c
  , constraint <name> check (  (b_id is null and c_id is not null)
                            or (b_id is not null and c_id is null)
                            )
  );
```

You could, if it helps your UI, create a view over that table that combines B_ID and C_ID into a single column.

But you have said you don't want 2 columns, why is that?

Comment: my tabels are automatically created and synced -> this would be a gigantic change is my code ):

Comment: @MarkusSchreiber Please edit that & any clarifications into your question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is hard is because the data model is wrong. A foreign key references only one table. A table can have more than one foreign key but each is separate. Apart from anything else, how would you know whether `bc_id` referenced `b.id` or `c.id`?

One explanation for this scenario is that table `A` should really be two tables, `BA` referencing `B` and `CA` referencing `C`. Alternatively `A` should reference a super-type table, of which `B` and `C` are sub-types. Without knowing the actual business domain it's hard to be sure.

Anyway, the path of least change is two columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make a new column in table A.

Then you can make a parent table to B and C.

```
tableBC:
  id
```

And then create a 1-1 relation with tables B and C to table BC.

```
tableB:
  id,
  parent -- 1-1 foreign key to tableBC

tableC:
  id,
  parent -- 1-1 foreign key to tableBC
```

Now, in table A

```
tableA:
  id,
  TableBCId -- foreign key to tableBC
```

We have solved a similar problem using this approach.